# MagickWand ./configure can't find MagickWand-config

Tags: bash, unix, path, configure

I've been trying unsuccessfully to install ImageMagick and am stuck at this point. I've dled and phpized MagickWand and am trying to run ./configure and get the error:

checking MagickWand-config in default path... configure: error: Cannot locate configuration program MagickWand-config

I've tried both export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
and export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin/

and have also tried adding the paths to my .bash_profile file. I've also confirmed that there is a MagickWand-config executable in my /opt/local/bin directory.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

Try `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` and then run `./configure`. Worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04 after grabbing MagickWand 1.0.8 source from http://www.magickwand.org/download/php/.

Comment: How to run ./configure?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check MagickWand-config - if it doesn't install,
2. Run `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev` in your server
3. Reference the [MagicWand-config man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/MagickWand-config.1.html) for further options